# How to use a simulation output in Matlab using Sim API

Tags: api, simulink

I am simulating a Simulink model(using script) and currently using a toworkspace block to first save the output data to workspace and then using these data for further processing in my script.

My simulink model has two outputs **velocity** and **acceleration**.

But in my script I want to simulate the model and meanwhile use the model outputs to be saved or further used without using the toworkspace block.

I tried:

```
set_param('mdl_name','SaveState','on','StateSaveName','State',...
         'SaveOutput','on','OutputSaveName','velocity');
data=Simulink.SimulationOutput;
```

I expected the data to have velocity values but it returns empty value.

*I need some suggestions regarding whether there is another way to use an API and access a particular simulation output after simulating it via script or a suggestion to improve the above script.*

Answer (score 0):

Several causes can lead to this behavior. I suggest you to run "sldemo_varsize_basic" in MATLAB command window. This will start a built-in application example of the "ToWorkspace" block. Compare the parameters of the "ToWorkspace" blocks in this model and your model + the "Data Import/Export" pane in the "Configuration Parameters". 
I was also using the "ToWorkspace"-based approach, but I changed to storing the results by "Signal Logging" ( in my application I found it more convenient to handle the results + there are no additional blocks required each time I want to log a new signal).
A complete list of ways to "Save Runtime Data from Simulation" is listed on the [linked](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/export-runtime-information.html)  Mathworks website.

Comment: I know accessing signals using data logging but i am expecting something without manipulating the model (for data logging i must change the signal line properties to enable it and toworkspace block must be added for the other way of signal access). I came accross the SIM command but have no clue how to use it successfully.